# Python syslog logger can't write more than 2048 chars

Tags: python, logging, limit, syslog

I'm trying to print some messages to syslog using Python's syslog logger. Simple logger as described in "[How to configure logging to syslog in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968669/how-to-configure-logging-to-syslog-in-python)":

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler()

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

my_logger.debug('this is debug')
```

But when I'm trying to print a very long message like `my_logger.debug('<<4000 chars>>')`, it is printing only first 2046 chars. Is there any such known limit in Python?

From what I could gather, Python supports a VERY big string input and all the arguments are passed as reference, so it should not be any problem in handling such large input. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe that's a syslog limitation and not a Python one. You could write your own handler that did whatever you wanted.

Comment: yeah, that could be the one. Before concluding that I just wanted to strike out python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rsyslogd limits to 2048 bytes per message by default, but you can set it using `$MaxMessageSize` parameter in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

> $MaxMessageSize , default 2k - allows to specify maximum
>   supported message size (both for sending and receiving).

Reference: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/global/index.html

Comment: The `$MaxMessageSize` default is now 8k.

Answer (score 0):

You should use GELF http://www.graylog2.org/about/gelf

> The Graylog Extended Log Format (GELF) avoids the shortcomings of
>   classic plain syslog:
>
> ```
> Limited to length of 1024 byte - Not much space for payloads like backtraces
> Unstructured. You can only build a long message string and define priority, severity etc.
> ```

You can read more from this [Does Syslog really have a 1KB message limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011986/does-syslog-really-have-a-1kb-message-limit)